# How to do a LIKE database query in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder, dql

This should be simple but I can't find a working example.  Here's a controller method that throws the error "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens".  I'm posting the "searchterm" variable successfully but can't get the query to work.  What is missing?  Thanks!

```
 public function searchAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $searchterm = $request->get('searchterm');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT n FROM AcmeNodeBundle:Node n WHERE n.title LIKE '% :searchterm %'")
             ->setParameter('searchterm', $searchterm);

    $entities = $query->getResult();

    return array('entities' => $entities);

}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Working example from my Symfony2 project:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb->where(
         $qb->expr()->like('u.username', ':user')
     )
     ->setParameter('user','%Andre%')
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 11):

You should dump the created query for easier debugging.

I can only suggest you also try the querybuilder:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$result = $qb->select('n')->from('Acme\NodeBundle\Entity\Node', 'n')
  ->where( $qb->expr()->like('n.title', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $searchterm . '%')) )
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult();
```

[doc](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

Answer (score 9):

I think this option also helps:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb->where('u.username like :user')
     ->setParameter('user','%hereIsYourName%')
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

WHERE n.title LIKE '% :searchterm %'

should be

WHERE n.title LIKE :searchterm

```
public function searchAction() {
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $searchterm = $request->get('searchterm');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT n FROM AcmeNodeBundle:Node n WHERE n.title LIKE :searchterm")->setParameter('searchterm', $searchterm);

    $entities = $query->getResult();

    return array('entities' => $entities);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `AcmeNodeBundle\Node`? In DQL `AcmeNodeBundle:Node` `:Node` - named parameter